# "Destroy the Asteroid" Game

Tags: java, beginner, game, homework, processing

I made this game for my computer science class.

Here is my professor's requirements:

> 1. Write a Processing program that draws a triangle in the middle of the window.
> 2. Rotate the triangle when the left and right arrow keys are pressed using the translate and rotate methods.
> 3. When the spacebar is hit, create a torpedo that appears to shoot out one of the vertices of the triangle. Note: if you do not want a
>      continuous stream of torpedoes generate when the space bar is held
>      down, you can use the PApplet’s keyReleased method instead of the
>      keyPressed method.
> 4. Create some number of large ellipses to represent asteroids. Have the asteroids move in random directions around the window, wrapping
>      around when they cross one of the window’s boundaries.
> 5. Have the torpedoes destroy the asteroids when they collide. (Using an ellipse for the torpedo will probably make the collision detection
>      easier.) When the asteroids are destroyed, create a Particle System
>      centered at the center of the asteroid to make it look like there was
>      an explosion.
> 6. Keep track of points based on the number of asteroids destroyed and display the total points in the window.
> 7. When an asteroid collides with the spaceship, destroy the spaceship and create a Particle System at the center of the colliding ship.
> 8. Include a button to restart the game when the spaceship is destroyed.

What kind of improvement should I make?

**Main:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class spaceMain extends PApplet {

    ArrayList<Torpedoes> TorpedoesList = new ArrayList<Torpedoes>();
    ArrayList<Asteroids> AsteroidsList = new ArrayList<Asteroids>();
    ArrayList<ParticleSystems> theList = new ArrayList<ParticleSystems>();
    ArrayList<Asteroids> smallList = new ArrayList<Asteroids>(); 

    float width = 1000;
    float height = 600;
    float angle;
    float numAsteroids = 10;
    float rXPos;
    float rYPos;

    int score;

    boolean sAlive = true;
    boolean gameIsOver = false;


    SpaceShip theSpaceShip;

    public void setup(){
      initializeGame();
      textSize(26);
    }//end set up  

    public void initializeGame(){
        angle = 0; 
        score = 0;
        rXPos = 440;
        rYPos = 140;

        theSpaceShip = new SpaceShip(0, 0,angle);


        while(AsteroidsList.size() < numAsteroids){
            Asteroids theAsteroid = new Asteroids(random(0,1000), random(0,600),random(50,80));
            while(theAsteroid.getXPos() > width/2 - 100 && theAsteroid.getXPos() < width/2 + 100 ){
                theAsteroid = new Asteroids(random(0,1000), random(0,600),random(50,80));
            } //end while
            AsteroidsList.add(theAsteroid);
        }//end while 


        Iterator<ParticleSystems> Piterator = theList.iterator();
        while(Piterator.hasNext()){
            Piterator.next();
            Piterator.remove();
        }//end while



        sAlive = true;
        gameIsOver = false;

    }//end initializeGame



    public void draw(){

        background(19,19,70);


        if(gameIsOver){
            text("You Lose !", 450, 100);

            Iterator<Asteroids> Asiterator = AsteroidsList.iterator();
             while(Asiterator.hasNext()){
                 Asiterator.next();
                 Asiterator.remove();
             }//end while

             Iterator<Torpedoes> Toiterator = TorpedoesList.iterator();
             while(Toiterator.hasNext()){
                 Toiterator.next();
                 Toiterator.remove();
             }//end while 

            fill(0,255,0); 
            rect(rXPos,rYPos, width/6, height/10);
            fill(0,0,0);
            text("Start again?",450,180);
        }else {
            text("score :" +score, 200,200);
        }//end else if





        fill(127,127,127);
        pushMatrix();
           translate(width/2, height/2);
           rotate(angle);
           if(sAlive){
               theSpaceShip.display(this);
           }//end if 
        popMatrix();






        for(Torpedoes theTorpedo: TorpedoesList){
            theTorpedo.display(this);
            theTorpedo.shootOut();
        }//end for

        for(Asteroids theAsteroid: AsteroidsList){
            theAsteroid.display(this);
            theAsteroid.aMove();
        }//end for 

        for(ParticleSystems theParticleSystem: theList){
            theParticleSystem.display(this);
            theParticleSystem.update();
            theParticleSystem.addParticle();
        }//end for 




         destroySpaceShip();
         destroyAsteroid();


    }//end draw 








    public void keyPressed(){
        if(key == ' '){
            TorpedoesList.add(new Torpedoes(width/2, height/2, angle));
        }else if(key == CODED){
            if(keyCode == LEFT){
                angle = angle - (float)0.2;
            } else if(keyCode == RIGHT){
                angle = angle + (float)0.2;
            }//end if
        }//end else if
    }//end keyPressed 


    public void destroySpaceShip(){

        for(Asteroids theAsteroid: AsteroidsList){
            if(distance(theAsteroid.getXPos(), theAsteroid.getYPos(), width/2, height/2) <= theAsteroid.getLength() ){
                theList.add(new ParticleSystems(width/2,height/2,1));
                sAlive = false;
                gameIsOver = true;
            }//end if 
        }//end for 
    }//end destroySpaceShip 


    public void destroyAsteroid(){

        Iterator<Torpedoes> Titerator = TorpedoesList.iterator(); 
        while(Titerator.hasNext()){
            Torpedoes theTorpedo = Titerator.next();
            Boolean collided = false;

            Iterator<Asteroids> Aiterator = AsteroidsList.iterator();
            while(Aiterator.hasNext()){
                Asteroids theAsteroid = Aiterator.next();
                if(distance(theAsteroid.getXPos(), theAsteroid.getYPos(), theTorpedo.getXPos(), theTorpedo.getYPos()) <= 50){
                     score = score + 1;
                     Aiterator.remove();
                     theList.add(new ParticleSystems(theAsteroid.getXPos(),theAsteroid.getYPos() ,1));
                     collided = true;
                }//end if 
            }//end while

            if(collided){
                Titerator.remove();
                if(TorpedoesList.size() < numAsteroids){
                    for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
                        Asteroids theAsteroid = new Asteroids(random(0,1000), random(0,600),random(50,80));
                        while(theAsteroid.getXPos() > width/2 - 200 && theAsteroid.getXPos() < width/2 + 200){
                            theAsteroid = new Asteroids(random(0,1000), random(0,600),random(50,80));
                        } //end while
                        AsteroidsList.add(theAsteroid);
                    }//end for 
                }//end if 
            }//end if 
        }//end while

    }//end destroyAsteriods


    float distance(float Ax, float Ay, float Tx, float Ty){
         return sqrt(sq(Ax-Tx) + sq(Ay-Ty));
    }//end distance

    public void mousePressed(){
        if(gameIsOver && mouseX <= rXPos+width/6 && mouseX >= rXPos && mouseY <= rYPos+height/10 && mouseY >= rYPos){
            initializeGame();
        }//end if
    }//end mousePressed






    public void settings(){
        size(1000,600);
    }// end settings

    public static void  main(String[] args){
        PApplet.main("spaceMain");
    }//end run processing 
}//end class
```

**`SpaceShip`:**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class SpaceShip {


    float xPos;
    float yPos;
    float angle;


    SpaceShip(float xInit, float yInit, float aInit){
        xPos = xInit;
        yPos = yInit;
        angle = aInit;
     }//end constructor


    void display(PApplet proc){
        proc.triangle(xPos+50, yPos, xPos-50, yPos-50, xPos-50, yPos+50);
        proc.fill(127,127,127);
        proc.stroke(127,127,127);
    }//end of display

    void up(){
        xPos = xPos + (float)Math.cos(angle)*10;
        yPos = yPos + (float)Math.sin(angle)*10;
    }//end up

    void down(){
        xPos = xPos - (float)Math.cos(angle)*10;
        yPos = yPos - (float)Math.sin(angle)*10;
    }//end down 

    float getXPos(){
        return xPos;
    }//end getxPos

    float getYPos(){
        return yPos;
    }//end getyPos
}//end spaceship class
```

**`Torpedoes`:**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Torpedoes {
      float xPos;
      float yPos;
      float angle;

      float xDir;
      float yDir;

      Torpedoes(float xInit, float yInit, float aInit){
          xPos = xInit;
          yPos = yInit;
          angle = aInit;
          xDir = (float)Math.cos(angle);
          yDir = (float)Math.sin(angle);
      }//end constructor;

      void display(PApplet proc){
          proc.fill(255,0,0);
              proc.pushMatrix();
              proc.translate(xPos, yPos);   
              proc.rotate(angle);
              proc.ellipse(0, 0, 40,20);
          proc.popMatrix();       

      }//end display 

      void shootOut(){
          xPos = xPos + 4*xDir;
          yPos = yPos + 4*yDir;


      }//end shoot out

      float getXPos(){
         return xPos;
      }//end getxPos

      float getYPos(){
         return yPos;
      }//end getyPos



}//end classTorpedoes
```

**`Asteroids`:**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Asteroids {

    float xPos;
    float yPos;
    float length;


    float xDir = (float)Math.random()*2-1;
    float yDir = (float)Math.random()*2-1;

    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;

    boolean alive = true;




    Asteroids(float xInit, float yInit, float lInit){
        xPos = xInit;
        yPos = yInit;
        length = lInit;
    }//end constructor

    void display(PApplet proc){
        proc.fill(230,230,20);
        proc.stroke(230,230,20);
        proc.ellipse(xPos, yPos, length,length);
    }//end display

    void aMove(){
        xPos = xPos + 2*xDir;
        yPos = yPos + 2*yDir;

        if(xPos < 0 || xPos > 1000){
            xDir = - xDir;
        }//end if

        if(yPos < 0 || yPos > 600){
            yDir = - yDir;
        }//end if 
    }//end aMove

    float getXPos(){
        return xPos;
    }//end getxPos

    float getYPos(){
        return yPos;
    }//end getyPos

    float getLength(){
        return length;
    }//end getLength


}//end class
```

**`Particles`:**

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Particles {



        float xPos;
        float yPos;

        float xDir;
        float yDir;

        float lifeSpan = 255; 

        Particles(float xPosInit, float yPosInit, float xDirInit, float yDirInit){
            xPos = xPosInit;
            yPos = yPosInit;
            xDir = xDirInit;
            yDir = yDirInit;
        }//end constructor

        void update(){
            xPos = xPos + xDir;
            yPos = yPos + yDir;
            lifeSpan = lifeSpan - 3;
        }// end update

        void display(PApplet proc){
            proc.fill(255,0,0, lifeSpan);
            proc.stroke(255,0,0, lifeSpan);
            proc.ellipse(xPos, yPos, 5, 5);
        }//end display

        boolean isAlive(){
            return (lifeSpan > 0);
        }
    }//end class
```

**`ParticleSystems`:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class ParticleSystems {
        ArrayList<Particles> particlesList = new ArrayList<Particles>(); 


        float xOrigin;
        float yOrigin;
        int numParticles;


        ParticleSystems(float xInit, float yInit, int numInit){
            xOrigin = xInit;
            yOrigin = yInit;
            numParticles = numInit;

            while(particlesList.size() < numParticles){
                addParticle();
            }//end while
        }//end construction 

        void addParticle(){
            particlesList.add(new Particles(xOrigin, yOrigin, 
                    (float) Math.random()*2 -1,(float) Math.random()*2 -1));
        }// end addParticle

        void display(PApplet proc){
            for(Particles theParticle: particlesList){
                theParticle.display(proc);
            }//end for 
        }//end display()

        void update(){
            Iterator <Particles> piterator = particlesList.iterator();

            int index = particlesList.size()-1;
            while(index >= 0){
                Particles theParticle = particlesList.get(index);
                theParticle.update();
                if(! theParticle.isAlive()){
                    particlesList.remove(index);
                }//end if
                index--;
            }//end while
        }//end update

}//end class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Formatting & look:

### Use proper access modifiers

All you methods and fields use the default package level visibility. Decreasing the scope of items to the lowest possible scope is recommended for clearer code. This is as simple of marking you methods and fields private or public where needed.

### Start field/variable names with a lowercase letter

> ```
> ArrayList<Torpedoes> TorpedoesList = new ArrayList<Torpedoes>();
> ArrayList<Asteroids> AsteroidsList = new ArrayList<Asteroids>();
> ...
> Iterator<Torpedoes> Titerator = TorpedoesList.iterator(); 
> ...
> Iterator<Asteroids> Aiterator = AsteroidsList.iterator();
> ```

In java, fields should start with a lowercase letter

```
ArrayList<Torpedoes> torpedoesList = new ArrayList<Torpedoes>();
ArrayList<Asteroids> asteroidsList = new ArrayList<Asteroids>();
...
Iterator<Torpedoes> tIterator = torpedoesList.iterator(); 
...
Iterator<Asteroids> aIterator = asteroidsList.iterator();
```

### Marking fields final when they are write once

> ```
> ArrayList<Torpedoes> TorpedoesList = new ArrayList<Torpedoes>();
> ArrayList<Asteroids> AsteroidsList = new ArrayList<Asteroids>();
> ArrayList<ParticleSystems> theList = new ArrayList<ParticleSystems>();
> ArrayList<Asteroids> smallList = new ArrayList<Asteroids>(); 
> ...
> ArrayList<Particles> particlesList = new ArrayList<Particles>();
> ```

By marking fields final, you cover the meaning that they should be edited using the methods only, as opposite to reinitiating them.

### Class names should start with a uppercase

> ```
> public class spaceMain extends PApplet {
> ...
> PApplet.main("spaceMain");
> ```

A common practise is to start class names with uppercase letters

## Logic issues

### Manual clearing of Collection

> ```
>         Iterator<Asteroids> Asiterator = AsteroidsList.iterator();
>          while(Asiterator.hasNext()){
>              Asiterator.next();
>              Asiterator.remove();
>          }//end while
>
>          Iterator<Torpedoes> Toiterator = TorpedoesList.iterator();
>          while(Toiterator.hasNext()){
>              Toiterator.next();
>              Toiterator.remove();
>          }//end while
> ```

The above can be made smaller using:

```
AsteroidsList.clear();
TorpedoesList.clear();
```

### Updating in the draw loop

You are updating your entities in your main draw loop, this will cause jitter in the movement of the entities as they are affected by the main fps.

### Don't use boxed objects if unboxed exist

> ```
> Boolean collided = false;
> ```

When using boolean with a uppercase letter, you are boxing the results, this means that a object is used instead a primitive. Using objects is slower than primitives, and should be avoided.

### Distances should be compared using the squared version

> ```
>             if(distance(theAsteroid.getXPos(), theAsteroid.getYPos(), width/2, height/2) <= theAsteroid.getLength() ){
>             ...
>             if(distance(theAsteroid.getXPos(), theAsteroid.getYPos(), theTorpedo.getXPos(), theTorpedo.getYPos()) <= 50){
> ```

Doing `number * number` is a cheap operation, doing `sqrt(number)` is a heavy operation. Avoid sqrt in favor of pow.